# In $Z_2[i]$, why is $(1+i)(1+i) = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

$i\cdot i$ = $-1 = 1 \in Z_2$, so $(1+i)(1+i) = 1+i+i+1 = 2+2i = 2(1+i)$ Why does this equal 0? Where has my (modular) arithmetic gone wrong?

Comment: Because $2x = (1+1)x = 0x = 0\,$ for all $x\ \ $

Comment: You can use 2 = 0 in $Z_2$

Comment: Note that $i^2=-1$ so you should end up with $2i$.

Comment: Also note that $i = 1 = \pm 1 = \pm i$ in $\Bbb{Z}_2[i]$ so $\Bbb{Z}_2[i] = \Bbb{Z}_2$. Adjoining a root of an equation to a field that already contains all the roots of the equation gives you back the same field.

Answer (score 5):

As $2 \equiv 0 \mod 2$ Therefore, $2=0$ in $\mathbb Z_2.$